# How to exclude certain tasks per default?

Tags: gradle

I added some plugins and and tasks to my gradle (multi-) project, that need quite a long time to be executed and should therefore only be done on the build server per default. Developers should just be able to call

```
gradlew build
```

to execute the essential steps for building and testing the application. On the build server, Jenkins in our case, I would like to add an additional parameter to enabled the aformentioned extra tasks. E.g.

```
gradlew build -buildserver
```

So my question is, how can I exclude certain tasks as my default and include them using a parameter or the like?

I tried `enabled =` which seems not to be possible, at least for the findBugs plugin:

```
allprojects {
  apply plugin: 'java'
  apply plugin: 'findbugs'

  ...

  findbugs {
    enabled = project.hasProperty('buildserver')
    ...
}
```

Comment: The for findbugs task is not `findbugs` but `findbugsMain`. Try: `findbugsMain.enabled = false`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since [Opal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/542270/opal) pointed me in the right direction, I did the following:
Run the build to find the task names and setting their `enabled` flag like this:

```
findbugsMain.enabled = project.hasProperty('buildserver')
findbugsTest.enabled = project.hasProperty('buildserver')
test.jacoco.enabled = project.hasProperty('buildserver')
pmdMain.enabled = project.hasProperty('buildserver')
pmdTest.enabled = project.hasProperty('buildserver')
```

I then added the flag to my Jenkins job and run the build like this:

```
gradlew clean build -P buildserver
```

Comment: I set these properties to false in the build file and then add specific tasks where I set them to true; so gradle build skips findbugs but gradle slowBuild does not. Similarly I have integrationTests only in my slow build.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is to add a predicate for the relevant tasks

```
findbugs.onlyIf { project.hasProperty('buildserver') }
```

You can read more about it in gradle documentation [skipping tasks][1] section.

Comment: I just followed the example provided by Tim but my solution will generally work for any task.

Comment: Yes, it will, however the answer isn't valid.

Comment: Disagree - general question (How to exclude certain tasks per default?), general answer. Anyway, forget it...